# Using TRY_PARSE in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, type-conversion, parse

I have a script in SQL Server 2012 like this:

```
Declare @ParamSPKDateFrom varchar(50), @SPKDateFrom date,

Select @SPKDateFrom = TRY_PARSE(@ParamSPKDateFrom AS date USING 'id-ID')
```

Can I convert this script to **SQL Server 2008**?

Answer (score 4):

`TRY_PARSE` is implemented in SQL Server 2012 and later as a thin layer over CLR Framework calls.

You could implement a replacement as a SQL Server 2008 CLR function.

For CLR details see [Parse date and time strings in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime) and for example [DateTime.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse#system-datetime-tryparse(system-string-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles-system-datetime@)).

Answer (score 3):

No, `TRY_PARSE()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012; there is no way to make an earlier version of the database engine understand that syntax.

In theory, you could create your own function that takes an argument and tries to parse it to a data type (I just [published one here, for `date`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7588/try-parse-functionality-sql-server-2008/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)), but you'd have to know how to handle all of the potential cultures that would be passed in as another argument (and it would be complicated to write a single function that accepted *any* data type; I would probably write `dbo.try_parse_date`, for example).

I wrote a two-part series on doing that for `TRY_CONVERT()` here:

- [Simulating TRY_CONVERT() in SQL Server 2008](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5411/simulating-tryconvert-in-sql-server-2008/)
- [Simulating TRY_CONVERT() in SQL Server 2008 – Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5412/simulating-tryconvert-in-sql-server-2008-part-2/)

...but you wouldn't be able to use the *exact* same syntax such that the code would be portable to newer versions *without your custom function* by only changing the function name to the built-in (e.g. you can't write a function that accepts arguments like `@ParamSPKDateFrom AS date USING 'id-ID'`).

I would also advise against calling your function `dbo.try_parse` because of obvious future naming conflicts (assuming you'll ever upgrade).

Or, maybe, just upgrade now.